# Need to split column which has mixed data

Tags: python

I need to split the column "country" because it includes "index and country name" in the same column. However, I got an error message. 
data frame:

```
df['country']
0             US
1          Spain
2             US
3             US
4         France
           ...  
150925     Italy
150926    France
150927     Italy
150928    France
```

### 150929     Italy

```
here is my codes:

# new data frame with split value columns 
new = data["Name"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) 

# making separate first name column from new data frame 
data["id"]= new[0] 

# making separate last name column from new data frame 
data["Country"]= new[1] 

# Dropping old Name columns 
data.drop(columns =["country"], inplace = True) 

# df display 
data
```

I've tried using a dictionary, key-value, but it did not work out.

```
----------------------------------------------------------- 
df['country']
0             US
1          Spain
2             US
3             US
4         France
           ...  
150925     Italy
150926    France
150927     Italy
150928    France
```

### 150929     Italy

```
here is my codes:

# new data frame with split value columns 
new = data["country"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True) 

# making separate first name column from new data frame 
data["id"]= new[0] 

# making separate last name column from new data frame 
data["Country"]= new[1] 

# Dropping old Name columns 
data.drop(columns =["country"], inplace = True) 

# df display 
data
```

I want to have separate columns for id and country:
id       country
0             US
1          Spain
2             US
3             US
4         France
           ...
150925     Italy
150926    France
150927     Italy
150928    France
150929     Italy

Comment: It's unclear what the error is. Can you add to the question the actual output you are getting? How do you know it is failing? Or, if you print the final variables, what is the output, and how are they different from what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

you may use following approche:

```
import pandas as pd 
lst = ['US','Spain','US','France','Italy','France','Italy','France'] 

ids=list(range(len(lst)))
df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
newdf= pd.DataFrame(list(zip(ids,lst)),columns =['id', 'country']) 
print (newdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are a bit confused. On `df['country']`you are getting a Series, Series are always shown with the index. If you want to get its values or index you can do

`df['country'].values`

`df['country'].index`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The question is bit unclear, so I'm giving two possible suggestions :

1 - If you actually have a column with numeric and string values combined, you can use the below code to split them into two separate columns.

```
INPUT :

      Name
    0 France
    1 India
    2 US
    3 Russia

CODE :

data[["ID","Country"]] = data["Name"].str.split(" ", n = 1, expand = True)
data=data.drop(["country"], axis=1)
```

2 - As Alfonso mentioned, df["Country"] is a series and will be displayed along with the index values. There might be some confusion because of that. Request you to make sure thats not the case.